# React Native - Accurate Current location(Latitude, Longitude)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

Hi I am using below code to get the accurate current latitude and longitude
but i am not able to get the accurate location, So can anybody suggest me how to get accurate current latitude and longitude in react native(Android and iOS).

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     (position) => {
       console.log(position);
       this.setState({
         latitude: position.coords.latitude,
         longitude: position.coords.longitude,
         error: null,
       });
     },
     (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
     // { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
   );
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get accurate Location and longitude in android manifest you can declare

**AndroidManifes.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this library [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

hope this help!